# Export in glb models from DAZ

Tags: materials, export

Dears,

I have created a character using Daz Studio (I do not have knowledge in 3D modeling). Then, I export it to Blender using the "Daz to Blender" tool. And the result is what I was expecting:

[image: model]

But when I try to export it in .glb, the texture are not exported:

[image: model]

Is there an easy way to force the exportation with the textures? I tried to check on the internet but I always found video of more than 20 minutes explaining how to create a material that will be exported and this is not what I am searching for. There are a lot of materials already present and I do not understand the method.

For those who would like to have the files, blend file and glb files can be found [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qm1xjAghn1F7AbZMSTrUXPsaKPr1cFbG/view?usp=sharing) (6.11 Mo).

Many thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures